# How to define a pointer to an array of class pointers of Size MAX in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I have an array of size `MAX` of class pointers.

How can I define a pointer to the same, and access member functions of `base`, `derived`, etc?

```
class base
{
public :
    base() {cout << "base class constructor" << endl;}
    virtual void g() {cout << "base :: g()" << endl;}
};

class derived_1 : public base
{
public :
    derived_1() : base() {cout << "derived_1 class constructor" << endl;}
    virtual void g() {cout << "derived_1 :: g()" << endl;}
};

class derived_2 : public derived_1
{
public :
    derived_2() : derived_1() { cout << "derived_2 class constructor" << endl;}
    void g(int) {cout << "derived_2 :: g()" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    base b;
    derived_1 d_1;
    derived_2 d_2;

    base* arr[MAX] = {&b, &d_1, &d_2};
    base *(*pArr)[MAX];

    pArr = arr;

    for (i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
    {
        pArr[i]->g();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get a compilation error:

> error: cannot convert 'base* [3]' to 'base* (*)[3]' in assignment

When I change it to below, it works, however it looks more like a hack to me, and method 1 looks more formal to me:

```
base* arr[3] = {&b, &d_1, &d_2};
base **pArr;

pArr = arr;

for (i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    pArr[i]->g();
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `arr` is a pointer of `MAX` pointers to `base`. `pArr` is a pointer to such array, you cannot simply assign one to the other. `&` is the address of operator.

Comment: it doesnt work for the same reason `int x = 42; int * p = x;` wont compile

Comment: though it is unclear why you think you would need `pArr`

Comment: `pArr[i]->g();` is totally wrong.  You want `arr[i]->g()`

Comment: Similarly, `pArr[i]->g()` should be `(*pArr)[i]->g()`

Comment: Have a look at std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> that is the current way of storing a dynamically allocated list of polymorphic objects

Comment: `arr` is converted into a pointer to its first element; `&arr[0]`.  Since the element type is `base*`, the type of that pointer is `base**`. `&arr` would a pointer to the array itself.

Comment: In your loop what exactly is wrong with the normal code `arr[i]->g();`? You've had a lot of advice on how to handle a pointer to an array, but I seriously doubt that is what you want. Pointers to arrays are a very obscure corner of C/C++. Your 'hack' is also perfectly legitimate code.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want the address of the array, not the array itself, when assigning it to a pointer to an array type:

```cpp
constexpr auto length = 1;
base* arr[length] = {&b};
base* (* pArr)[length] = &arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet you declared a pointer of the type `base * ( * )[MAX]`

```
base *(*pArr)[MAX];
```

However you are trying to initialize it with a pointer of the type `base **`

```
pArr = arr;
```

due to implicit conversion of the array designator `arr` to pointer to its first element. However there is no implicit conversion between the pointer types `base **` and `base * ( * )[MAX]`.

Instead you need to write

```
pArr = &arr;

for (i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
{
    ( *pArr )[i]->g();
}
```

In this subexpression `( *pArr )[i]` at first the pointer `pArr` is dereferenced `( *pArr)` and yields an lvalue reference to the original array `arr` that is used in the subscript operator `( *pArr )[i]` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

In the second code snippet code snippet the pointer `pArr` is declared as having the pointer type `base **` and the initializing expression (due to the implicit conversion mentioned above) also has the same type `base **`. So the second code snippet is valid.

From the C++17 Standard (7.2 Array-to-pointer conversion)

> 1 An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown
> bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The
> temporary materialization conversion (7.4) is applied. The result is a
> pointer to the first element of the array.

The difference between the first code snippets and the second code snippet is that in the second code snippet you need not to dereference the pointer `pArr` to get a pointer to the first element of the array of the type `base **`.

Pay attention to that in this declaration

```
base* arr[MAX] = {&b, &d_1, &d_2};
```

the identifier `MAX` must be equal exactly to `3`. Otherwise in this for loop

```
for (i=0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
```

null pointers can be dereferenced that results in undefined behavior. Or if the value of `MAX` is greater than 3 then you should write the for loop like

```
for (i=0 ; i < MAX && ( *pArr )[i] != nullptr; i++)
```